# Where to store media files on a shared linux server

Tags: linux, directory-structure

I want to start using our home server as a media server for movies and shows, the question is where is the most appropriate place to store them?

The most appropriate places seems to be:

- /var
- My user directory
- Create a new user specifically for media and store stuff there

Ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its up to you really, I store all my media in /home/{name}/videos and share it with samba. No problems with that.

You can store it in /var; nothing wrong with that either.

There is only problems if you are working in a multi-user environment. If that was the case, I would suggest you store personal files in /home/{name} and shared files in /var/

Provided you don't have any extra partitions, it does not matter where you put the files.

Comment: Well, it's sort of a multi user environment but the other users doesn't have home directories as they are only for mounting shares. Currently I'm storing everything in my home directory.

Comment: Then i would put the data in /var/samba/ or something. However if it works, dont fix it, its good practice to only have files in your home directory accessible and read by you otherwise you run into problems with file ownership but if that's not a problem then dont worry about it.

Comment: I know, believe me :D /var/shared/ it is!

Answer (score 5):

In my understanding of [LHS 2.3](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM) I would place them in a subdirectory of `/srv/`. I tend to use a subdirectory in `/srv/exports/` to store shared files, like in your case `/srv/exports/media/`. I name it "exports" so it is not related to Samba (as you can also want to share it in NFS, AFP,...).